# Nested LINQ with multiple lists

Tags: c#, linq

I think this is just a personal code problem, but I just can't see how I'm supposed to return the `IsIdentifier` bool from this nested object. `dp` has a list of `dd`'s, and `dd` has a list of `supportedformats`, and one `supportedformat` has a list of `parameters`, and in `parameter` is a property (bool) called `isIdentifier` and I want to return it.

```cs
parameters.Add(new SupportedParameter
    {
        Name = name,
        Version = version,
        IsIdentifier = dp.Where(dp => dp.dd
            .Where(dd => dd.SupportedFormats
                .Where(sf => sf.Parameters.Where(sp => sp.Name == name).FirstOrDefault().IsIdentifier)
                )
            )
    }
);
```

Errors:

> - Cannot implicitly convert type `IEnumerable<SupportedFormat>` to `bool`.
> - Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate type

Also can somebody tell me how to format the code on stackoverflow? Because I'm on a different pc and usually TAB and SHIFT + TAB do the trick. But it didn't work so I tried CTRL + [ or CTRL + ] and these don't work either.

Comment: @Self They are asking about formatting the code in the question, not in VS.  I typically do that in a separate editor first where you can select multiple lines and do Tab or Shift Tab to add or remove indentation.

Comment: But that's not the thing that really has priority. I just don't understand how to return the property I want in the LINQ statement. I just wanted to know how to format so it's easier for you guys to read on here

Comment: @juharr, you got me. I didn't even read the question. the only think that look like a question catch my eyes.  For Op, I will recommend [ask] and [mre]. especially pretend you are talking to a busy collegue that would like me give a default answer if you leave that door open ^^

Comment: Are you sure you can compile a phrase like `dp.Where(dp => dp.dd`? Isn't there a problem in `dp`?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Oh wait you can't (I think), but how else would you do it? With Foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your code, it appears that you want to find the first deeply nested `Parameter` with `Name == name` and then return its `IsIdentifier` boolean property.

You can reduce the complexity of this operation by "flattening" out all the nested collections, so you'll end up with one big collection containing every `Parameter` across all the parent objects, by using the LINQ `SelectMany` extension method.

Here's how I would approach your specific case:

```
...

IsIdentifier = dps
                .SelectMany(dp => dp.dds)
                .SelectMany(dd => dd.SupportedFormats)
                .SelectMany(sf => sf.Parameters)
                .FirstOrDefault(parameter => parameter.Name == name)?.IsIdentifier ?? false;

...
```

The `?.IsIdentifier ?? false` part is just a fallback in case there are no Parameters with the specified name - it will just set `IsIdentifier` to false in that case.

Comment: Dang, that's some big brain stuff :0 Thank you. Btw what's that `? ??` statement called? It's not a ternary, right?

Comment: The `?.` is called the [Null Conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0#null-conditional-operator). It's basically a more succinct way of doing a null check and it also can be chained like `a?.b?.c?.d`. The `??` is called the [Null-Coalescing Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) which can be read as "return the left operand if it's not null, else return the right one if it is".